# Error while importing JSON file in r

Tags: json, r

I am trying to import a json file in r. 
Have installed necessary packages & libraries.
But keep on getting an error.

```
Error: lexical error: invalid string in json text.
                                       temp.jsonl
                     (right here) ------^
```

My code is as below -

```
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)
library(RJSONIO)
install.packages("rjson")
install.packages("RJSONIO")
json_data_raw<-fromJSON("temp.jsonl")
```

Thanks

Comment: if you are reading the file from disk you can use the wrapper function `jsonlite::read_json()`. Is there a typo in your file name?

Comment: Yes I am reading it from disk , I will give try with read_json. Actually the original file i got had big long name i just renamed it to temp. I dont think i am doing typo in code while importing. Thanks

Comment: No worries, I only mention the typo because I've not seen the extension `.jsonl` before.

Comment: exactly even i am seeing .jsonl for the first time. As far as i know JSON Lines is a convenient format for storing structured data that may be processed one record at a time.

Comment: Looking at this [link](http://jsonlines.org), it says *Each Line is a Valid JSON Value*, which I think is a good hint.

Comment: i tried with read_json & it looks like it is able to read data through file . however i am getting new error now. looks like some parsing issue.Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
          ate": "RI", "zip": "83973"}} {"id": "876ff718291d4397bb1e047
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: Thanks for kevin for your help. I was able to fix the issue & move forward

Comment: `jsonlite::read_json()` is still expecting to find valid json objects, not individual lines. Try `?jsonlite::stream_in` in stead.

Comment: @SymbolixAU, thanks for that, I will use that function in future. I think you should put `df <- stream_in(file("temp.jsonl"))` down as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read lines of JSON you can use the `jsonlite::stream_in` function.

```
df <- jsonlite::stream_in(file("temp.jsonl"))
```

#### Reference

> The jsonlite stream_in and stream_out functions implement line-by-line processing of JSON data over a connection, such as a socket, url, file or pipe

[JSON streaming in R](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/jsonlite-streaming/)

Comment: I did note that promoting the first row was not available as an argument. I would add `colnames(df) <- unlist(df[1, ]); df <- df[-1, ]` to be tidy.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines(filepath), collapse=",")))
```

Was able to fix the issue and create dataframe in r. 
Thanks guys.